# Where can I learn System Center Configuration Manager quickly?

Tags: sccm-2012

I've got 20 tabs open each with a hierarchical set of links that include videos, guides, and more links to more videos and guides.  It's too much.  Are there any good guides that one can learn some essentials for small businesses without getting neck deep in minutia?

More or less, I need to learn how to create and manage collections, deploy OS's both from winPE and remotely, create and manage advertisements, create and manage windows images, and possibly push updates out to applications.

Switching to another system management is not an option.  I don't mind learning the ins and outs, I just want a workable knowledge set first, a bigger picture practical vocation level training.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

[Technet Virtual labs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/bb467605.aspx) are your friend. They are a bit slow (as is the site) but they will walk you though all the basics, and you get to actually TRY and DO on them.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried a couple of those today and they were simulations with no direction.  I don't know if my browser is the issue or what.  But it simulated the console just fine, but it didn't walk me through anything.